# Multilanguage C# user interface, Arabic language

Tags: c#, user-interface, arabic, multilingual, revert

I am developing a multi-language user-interface in C# and have a problem with the Arabic language:

I inverted all the components of the UI, but I am not able to write the text from right to left. I am not sure whether it is possible or there is something related to the OS that allows to do that.

I am using some .resx files with a string table to store the texts in the different languages.

Is there a way to write RIGHT-TO-LEFT text on a non-arabic PC?

Comment: Very unclear, don't forget to use (say) TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your OS. You should install Arabic Language on Your System, then add it to your Keyboard/screen languages in the control panel.

How to do this depends on your OS version:

If you use **Windows Seven** or **Vista**:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/install-arabic-language-on-to-windows-7/6c6ab876-4679-488e-b72b-94e603a35333

If you use **Windows XP**:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821080

For any older versions just do a quick search on Google.

Hope to be helpful